# Unexpected Behavior of 'config.assets.prefix' in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have set the following configuration variable in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
```

In Rails 3, this would have meant that in development, my application would look for assets in  `public/dev-assets`, rather than `public/assets` to avoid the risk of loading precompiled assets that might be present.

However in Rails 4, setting this parameter and running `rake assets:precompile` now adds precompiled assets to `public/dev-assets`.

It seems like this prefix is being used for both where Rails places precompiled assets AND where rails looks for assets. This means Rails will always pull assets from the same location it places precompiled assets, meaning potentially stale precompiled assets obscure the most current assets.

**So how do I achieve the same thing in Rails 4? How can I precompile my assets to a different directory than the one rails looks for assets in?**

Console output from `rake assets:precompile`:

`[2014-01-23T11:48:35.766582 #4234]  INFO -- : Writing /path/to/app/public/dev-assets/application-1b403217ee27653d8d1299aeb242462b.js
I, [2014-01-23T11:48:35.819090 #4234]  INFO -- : Writing /path/to/app/public/dev-assets/application-8e258453df56d80e1a8b9b8a8e6f8db4.css`

Comment: in which env config file did you write `config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"`

Comment: @dax `config/environments/development.rb` (Added to question).

Comment: what is the behavior you want?  if you're running `assets:precompile` in the development env, isn't this expected behavior?

Comment: @dax With Rails 3, setting config.assets.prefix to a value other than `/assets` (for example `/dev-assets`, meant that while rails still precompiled assets to `public/assets`, it tried to pull assets in development mode from `public/dev-assets`, ensuring assets loaded were always fresh and not (potentially stale) precompiled assets.

Comment: Your assets belong in `app/assets/**/*`, when they're compiled they will go to `/public/` + wherever you dictate with `config.assets.prefix`. I'm struggling to understand your question. Are you serving compiled assets in development? Obviously rails looks for compiled assets in the place where you compile them to ...

Comment: @MikeCampbell In Rails 3.x it didn't. It would precompile assets to `public/assets` regardless of the value of `config.assets.prefix`, however it would try and pull assets from `public/#{config.assets.prefix}`. This meant you could avoid precompiled assets being used in development when running a server.

Comment: Not sure what Rails 3 version you were using but certainly in Rails 3.2.x compiled assets are written to the `config.assets.prefix` directory: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: Apologies for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been using `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, so that assets were precompiled in the production environment (where `config.assets.prefix` was still at the default) to `public/assets` locally.